# Why is my hamburger menu on mobile menus going under my hero image instead of pushing it down

Tags: html, css, responsive, hamburger-menu

I have a responsive nav everything is fine but this, my hamburger menu when opened, is going under my hero image under the menu like the backgroud image of the hero image is covering it, I want it to push down the hero image and display it on mobile screens.

[image: image (blue is the ham menu and the hero mage is above it)]

You can see it on [my Website](https://ezcoderz.com/)

or

Here is my code for it

HTML

```
    <nav class="navbar">
        <!-- LOGO -->
        <div class="logo">EzcoderZ</div>
        <!-- NAVIGATION MENU -->
        <ul class="nav-links">
            <!-- USING CHECKBOX HACK -->
            <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox_toggle" />
            <label for="checkbox_toggle" class="hamburger">&#9776;</label>
            <!-- NAVIGATION MENUS -->
            <div class="menu">
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html">contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="pricing.html">Pricing</a></li>

            </div>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <div class="hero-image">
        <div class="hero-text">
            <h1 style="font-size:50px">EzcoderZ</h1>
            <p>I am a coder</p>
            <button>Hire me</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
/* UTILITIES */
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

a {
 text-decoration: none;
}
li {
 list-style: none;
}

/* NAVBAR STYLING STARTS */
.navbar {
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: space-between;
 padding: 20px;
 background-color: black;
 color: #fff;
}
.nav-links a {
margin: none;
 color: #fff;
}

.nav-links a:hover {
text-decoration: none;
background: none;
}
/* LOGO */
.logo {
 font-size: 32px;
}
/* NAVBAR MENU */
.menu {
 display: flex;
 gap: 1em;
 font-size: 18px;
}
.menu li:hover {
 background-color: red;
 border-radius: 5px;
 transition: 0.3s ease;
}
.menu li {
 padding: 5px 14px;
}


/*RESPONSIVE NAVBAR MENU STARTS*/
/* CHECKBOX HACK */
input[type=checkbox]{
 display: none;
} 
/*HAMBURGER MENU*/
.hamburger {
 display: none;
 font-size: 24px;
 user-select: none;
}
/* APPLYING MEDIA QUERIES */
@media (max-width: 768px) {
.menu { 
 display:none;
 position: absolute;
 background-color:teal;
 right: 0;
 left: 0;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 16px 0;
}
.menu li:hover {
 display: inline-block;
 background-color:#4c9e9e;
 transition: 0.3s ease;
}
.menu li + li {
 margin-top: 12px;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .menu{
 display: block;
}
.hamburger {
 display: block;
}
.dropdown {
 left: 50%;
 top: 30px;
 transform: translateX(35%);
}
.dropdown li:hover {
 background-color: #4c9e9e;
}
} 



.hero-image {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url("img/herobg.jpg");
  height: 90%;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
}

.hero-text {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: white;
}

.hero-text button {
  border: none;
  outline: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 25px;
  color: black;
  background-color: #ddd;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.hero-text button:hover {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
}
```

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour] first. Then 
read [how to ask questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). After 
that edit the question to meet the guidelines and provide 
a [repro] for debugging details. Please also read: [Can I just link to my website?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/)

Comment: Position the menu fixed or absolute at a higher z-index. And what tacoshy said... it wont push the image down, but without a code example.. good luck.

Answer (score 0):

sry dude i get it wrong use this code posion relative for your menu and after that respansive look at the img[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AjKVX.jpg)

Comment: I added it but I want the hamburger menu to appear under the menu not in it